# React Native Element type is invalid: expected a string Skeleton PlaceHolder Package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

im trying to use this package [Skeleton-PlaceHolder](https://github.com/chramos/react-native-skeleton-placeholder) my React Native App i followed installtion steps and i tried both two ways to use this Package but when i run my app i get this [ Render ] error

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)

[image: Screenshot]

**Code :-
App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import  SkeletonPlaceholder  from "./node_modules/react-native-skeleton-placeholder";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SkeletonPlaceholder>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <View style={{ width: 60, height: 60, borderRadius: 50 }} />
        <View style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}>
          <View style={{ width: 120, height: 20, borderRadius: 4 }} />
          <View
            style={{ marginTop: 6, width: 80, height: 20, borderRadius: 4 }}
          /> 
        </View>
      </View>
    </SkeletonPlaceholder>
  );
};
```

Comment: Could you share your current code?

Comment: @DavidScholz i have added the code in the question